# Identify all instances of a string in an array and return the row above

Tags: excel-formula

Identify all instances of a string in an array and return the rows above.

Using INDEX/MATCH combo only identifies the first instance in the array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep - the lookup/index/match functions seek one instance only.

If this is a tickbox-style problem, the array of 'options' is small, and you just need a block/chunk of text including all the 'options selected,' consider using IF() and CONCAT():

| Responses | val1 | val2 | val3 | summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| response 1 | x | x |  | =CONCAT(IF(B2="x","val1 ",""), IF(C2="x","val2 ",""), IF(D2="x","val3 ","")) |

If you really need "row above", substitute the row above for the value strings (instead of val1, use B1, etc.).

It's not *pretty* data in the summary cell ... but maybe this will help you move ahead.

If the string is inside another string (like a block of text or something), the IF() test will be more complicated but this approach should still work.